# gettext localization is not working

Tags: post-meta, localization

I'm trying to translate the post date using  __() function. But it is not working. The post date still displayed in English.

What are you the other options to localize the post date(posted-on).

```
 printf(__('<span class="posted-on"><a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> %3$s</a></span>', 'colormag'), esc_url(get_permalink()), esc_attr(get_the_time()), $time_string
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends how and where you use this string. Possibly, you have to localize the date according to the site settings:

```
<?php

$date_format = get_option( 'date_format' );

$timestamp = strtotime( get_the_time() );

$localized_date = date_i18n( $date_format, $timestamp );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It displays the post date like this **September 26, 2018**

Comment: Should I implement the `$date_format`, `$timestamp,`  `$localized_date` in inc/functions.php because I'm using the the strings in the same file?

Comment: Just mention the file where do you use it and show us the code! It becomes much more funny and useful when other people can find something they are search for!

Comment: Thank you Max Yudin very much , I solved the problem :)